# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_MM_QC_DATA_MACH_JUN"
    (PSEC VARCHAR2,
      PCAT VARCHAR2,
      PSUB VARCHAR2,
      PMACHINE VARCHAR2,
      SREFDATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) as
BEGIN
    OPEN SREFDATA FOR
        select S.DESCRIPTION as SECTION, 
               MT.CODE as MACHINE_TYPE, 
               MH.MACH_NO,
               MH.ID_MM_SPINMACHINE_RW_H as ID_MM_MACHINE, 
               S.ID_MM_SPINSECTION, 
               MT.CODE    || ' - ' || MH.MACH_NO as Machine
        from MM_SPINMACHINE_H MH
        left join MM_MACHINETYPE MT 
            on MT.ID_MM_MACHINETYPE = MH.ID_MM_MACHINETYPE
        left join MM_SPINSECTION S 
            on S.ID_MM_SPINSECTION = MT.ID_MM_SPINSECTION
        where MH.REC_TYPE <> '5'
        and s.id_mm_sec = PSEC
        union all
        select ms.DESCRIPTION as section, 
               mg.group_desc as machine_type, 
               mm.machine_code as MACH_NO, 
               id_mm_machine as id_mm_machine,
               MS.ID_MM_SPINSECTION, 
               mg.group_desc || ' - ' || mm.machine_code as Machine
        from MM_MACHINE MM
        left join mm_spinsection ms
            on mm.id_mm_sec = ms.ID_MM_SPINSECTION
        left join mm_group mg 
            on mm.id_mm_group_mc_typ = mg.id_mm_group
        where mm.record_typ <> '5'
        and mm.id_mm_sec = PSEC
        order by 1,2,3;
END;
```

I got error in

> Error: PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00904: "S"."ID_MM_SEC": invalid identifier
>   Line: 19 Text: AND S.ID_MM_SEC = PSEC Error:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   Line: 13 Text: select S.DESCRIPTION as SECTION, MT.CODE as MACHINE_TYPE, MH.MACH_NO

Please advice.

Comment: Statement ignored is a generic error message. You need to paste the whole of the error stack if you expect us to help.

Comment: you mean this ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. For future reference, please **edit the question** to include additional information. Code especially is hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

This error message is the PL/SQL compiler saying, *I found one error in the SQL I'm not going to check for any more*. So the crucial message is the one which identifies the error. In your case it is this:

> ORA-00904: "S"."ID_MM_SEC": invalid identifier

This is the compiler telling you table `MM_SPINSECTION` does not have a column called `ID_MM_SEC`. You need to check your table definition and get the actual column name.

Comment: Okay , got it. Thanks a lot Sir.
I'm first time to use this ask question.
thanks for your help.